# Strange top-margin in JPanel with added Image in JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, jai

I add some images to a `JPanel`. Therefore, I add a single image to a `JLabel` as an `ImageIcon` and add this to the main `JPanel`. Although I set the bounds (setBounds) to the image-size, there is a margin of a few pixel on top of the image shown below.

[image http://w752749.open.ge.tt/1/files/64dsvTG/0/blob/x675](http://w752749.open.ge.tt/1/files/64dsvTG/0/blob/x675)

I also tried to add the images as `DisplayJai()`, without success (with `DisplayJai`, the images have also been croped in a strange way).

The important part of the code is

```
    JPanel srcJPanel = new JPanel();
    srcJPanel.setBounds(posW, posH, width, height);
    srcJPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN.darker(), 2));

    Image image = newImage.getScaledImg().getAsBufferedImage();
    JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    l.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED.darker(), 2));
    srcJPanel.add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    MainPanel.add(srcJPanel);
    this.validate();
```

Can anyone help me with this margin?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1) `setBounds`  Don't do that, that is probably the core of the problem.  Instead use layouts.  2) It might be more interesting to see the images used.  Can you upload one (**small in bytes**) image that displays the problem?  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) Interesting screenshot, is that image in the BG done as a time-lapse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setBounds method should be used only if you have "null" layout on your MainPanel, otherwise with each its validation your bounds will be reset to default layout bounds. To set "null" layout - just pass null into MainPanel's setLayout method.

Also using "null" layout is unnecessary in most cases. You can simply use existing layouts or write your own to avoid problems you might have using "null" layout.

Anyway the code you have provided is not enough to see the actual problem - better post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).